# How to add space inside multiple cells in Excel 2010

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2010

I would like quickly insert or add space to the beginning of text in multiple cells (rows) simultaneously. Is there any formula to do so?

Comment: Is using VBA script an option?

Answer (score 1):

If `VBA script` is an option then try this.

Create a button and assign this to it;

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    i = 1
    While i < 10
        Cells(i, 1).Value = " " + Cells(i, 1).Value
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Just remember when using the `Cells` command, it references the cells using numbers only and is reversed (Row, Column), so cell `A1` would be `1,1` and cell `H5` would be `5,8`.